# C# image size gets down when i rotate it

Tags: c#, image, user-interface

In c# i have a navigator placed on a xz plane what seems like this [navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XEro.png)

I found a method that provides oppurtunity of rotating any image by degrees what i exactly want to have but it also resizes image and after rotating for few times image scales that much even becomes invisible.
Here is the code , how should i edit it ?

```
private Bitmap RotateImage(Bitmap bmp, float angle)
    {
        float height = bmp.Height;
        float width = bmp.Width;
        int hypotenuse = System.Convert.ToInt32(System.Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(height * height + width * width)));
        Bitmap rotatedImage = new Bitmap(hypotenuse, hypotenuse);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(rotatedImage))
        {
            g.TranslateTransform((float)rotatedImage.Width / 2, (float)rotatedImage.Height / 2); //set the rotation point as the center into the matrix
            g.RotateTransform(angle); //rotate
            g.TranslateTransform(-(float)rotatedImage.Width / 2, -(float)rotatedImage.Height / 2); //restore rotation point into the matrix
            g.DrawImage(bmp, (hypotenuse - width) / 2, (hypotenuse - height) / 2, width, height);
        }
        return rotatedImage;
    }
```

Comment: A few hints: Make sure you always rotate the original and not a rotated version or else the quality will degrade. Also: Make sure you set the Dpi-Resolution of the original to the screen resolution. -Also: A rotated image will need more space unless you have started with a large enough size. I would use a png with transparency. And don't use the draw overload that changes the size, which is probably the actual issue!! All you really need is the position!

Comment: i do use a png with transparent background but i need to rotate it

Comment: The last point is the main one..

Comment: what should i do

Answer (score 0):

```
private Bitmap RotateImage(Image img,float angle)
    {
        
        Bitmap rbmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height);
        rbmp.SetResolution(img.HorizontalResolution, img.VerticalResolution);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(rbmp);
        g.TranslateTransform(rbmp.Width/2, rbmp.Height / 2);
        g.RotateTransform(angle);
        g.TranslateTransform(-rbmp.Width / 2, -rbmp.Height / 2);
        g.DrawImage(img, new PointF(0, 0));
        return rbmp;
    }
```

this fixed it